# Recursive vector return

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

I already created a function which recursive calling itself to add new elements to vector until `vector.size() < 4` and when `vector.size() == 4` function returns this modified vector with 4 elements.

However I'm can't figure it out how to modify the code below to get the same result without passing a vector in first call **(function should create a new vector in first call and in each next call add new element until `vector.size() < 4`)**

#### For instance:

- first call `func();`, create a vector and `push_back(vec.size() + 1)`, vector items: `1`
- second call `func(vec)`, modify passed vector adding new item, vector items: `1, 2`
- third call `func(vec)`, modify passed vector adding new item, vector items: `1, 2, 3`
- fourth call `func(vec)`, modify passed vector adding new item, vector items: `1, 2, 3, 4`
- return created vector with items: `1, 2, 3, 4` in first call

### Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<int> func (vector<int>& vec)
{    
    if (vec.size() < 4)
    {
        vec.push_back((vec.size() + 1));        
        func(vec);    
    }
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> v;
    vector <int> my_vector = func(v);
    cout << "vector items from main: " << endl;
    for (auto &i : my_vector)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

### Output:

```sh
vector items from main: 
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: For maintainability purpose, it is a bad idea that your function `func` both return the modified vector in the parameter and as the return value. GIven that you add value first, using the parameter is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do:

```
std::vector<int> func(std::vector<int> vec = {})
{    
    if (vec.size() < 4)
    {
        vec.push_back(vec.size() + 1);        
        vec = func(std::move(vec));    
    }
    return vec;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b57faaf7c91191ea)

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
std::vector<int> func() {
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        result.push_back(result.size() + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Recursion is not at all appropriate here.